# Can't insert state values into an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state in my class:

```
this.state = {
  inputValue: "",
  todos: []
}
```

In an arrow function, I am trying to `setState` in order to put `inputValue` into `todos`.

```
this.setState({ inputValue: "", todos: [...this.state.todos, {this.state.todos.length: this.state.inputValue}] })
```

However, when I try to insert the `inputValue` and the number, it gives an error. Any help is appreciated as I am new to React.

Comment: Is the todos array supposed to be an array of Strings or Objects? I ask that because I don't understand why are you giving the array length as a key when setting the state.

Comment: It is an array of objects

Comment: USED HOOK USESTATE IS BETTER

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a resulting `todos` array like this:

```
[
  {0: "something"},
  {1: "Else"}
]
```

The square bracket notation is needed to use a variable as the object key.

```
this.setState({
    inputValue: "",
    todos: [
      ...this.state.todos,
      { [this.state.todos.length]: this.state.inputValue }
    ]
});
```